# Apoc issue docker-compose.yml related with Neo4j in my Spring Boot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, neo4j

As I cannot get Neo4j Contanier working, I think there is a problem in my docker-compose.yml

When I run this command (`docker-compose up -d`), It works.

I got an error shown below when I try to calculate the shortest path through `Dijkstra`

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.algo.dijkstra` registered for this database instance.   
Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

How can I fix it?

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j-db:
    image: neo4j:4.1
    container_name: app-neo4j-db
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "neo4j/123456"
      NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: '["apoc"]'
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: apoc.\\\*,gds.\\\*
      dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address: neo4j-db:7687
      dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: neo4j-db:7687
    healthcheck:
      test: cypher-shell --username neo4j --password 123456 'MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n);' # Checks if neo4j server is up and running
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  app:
    image: 'springbootneo4jshortestpath:latest'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: SpringBootNeo4jShortestPath
    depends_on:
      neo4j-db:
        condition: service_healthy # Wait for neo4j to be ready
    links:
      - neo4j-db
    environment:
      NEO4J_URI: bolt://neo4j-db:7687
      NEO4J_USER: neo4j
      NEO4J_PASSWORD: 123456

volumes:
  app-neo4j-db:
```

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootNeo4jShortestPath)

Comment: In Unix in general, environment variable values can only be strings.  If you mean to set the environment variable value to a string with square brackets like that you need some sort of YAML quoting like `'["apoc"]'`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment

it should be:

```
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH="neo4j/123456"
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*,gds.\\\*
      - dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=neo4j-db:7687
      - dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=neo4j-db:7687
```

or

```
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "neo4j/123456"
      NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: ["apoc"]
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: apoc.\\\*,gds.\\\*
      dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address: neo4j-db:7687
      dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: neo4j-db:7687
```

Besides, you can't assign array in NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS and it's better to quote the values eg: "neo4j-db:7687"

Comment: it should have a quote `NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc"]'`
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/operations/#docker-neo4jlabs-plugins